# Select multiple arrays inside multidimensional JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

For example i want to edit multiple arrays at the same time by putting them in a variable and reverse them. Can this be done with more then 1 array? Something like `fruitColorsArr[0] & [1] & [2]` .

```js
var fruitColorsArr=[
    {
  "apple": "red",
  "banana": "yellow",
  "pear": "green",

 },
 {
  "apple": "red",
  "banana": "yellow",
  "pear": "green",

 },
 {
  
  "apple": "red",
  "banana": "yellow",
  "pear": "green",
 }
    ]

var fruitColors = Object.keys(fruitColorsArr[0]);
       fruitColors.reverse();
       console.log(fruitColors);
```

Comment: It's not clear. Can you please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54328630/edit) and post the exact output you're expecting for this input?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fruitColorsArr=[
    {
  "apple0": "red",
  "banana0": "yellow",
  "pear0": "green",

 },
 {
  "apple1": "red",
  "banana1": "yellow",
  "pear1": "green",

 },
 {
  
  "apple2": "red",
  "banana2": "yellow",
  "pear2": "green",
 }
    ]
    
    var result = [].concat(fruitColorsArr.map(fruit => (Object.keys(fruit).reverse())));
console.log(result)
```